# Using a variable inside a paragraph in JQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, cordova

I'm using JQuery mobile together with PhoneGap, and I'v been trying to show a string of text on the phone screen through a html page. Most of the text is always the same, but some parts I want to be controlled by variables which I have created inside a namespace using javascript:

```
$.Game = 
{ 
    gName: "global name" 
};
```

I then want to use this variable in the text I want to display, I have tried to find a way to fit it into a paragraph, but it needs to be inside a script tag. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: So you want to get `$.Game.gName` into a `<p>`? `$('#thePId').html($.G.gName);` But you'll have to put that in some event (like a button click or $(document).ready())

Comment: If you give a little more information about when you want the `<p>`'s contents set to the variable, we can help more.

Comment: What I tried to do was basically: "<p>Hi there + $.Game.gName + . More text osv</p>". I want to refer to a variable with a paragraph.

Comment: but when? When the screen loads? When some event happens? Does the value have to change multiple times or be set once?

Comment: It only needs to be set to the variable when the screen is loaded. Any further changes to the variable will not be done while the text is showing.

Comment: then go with jeff's answer below, similar to my initial comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
<p id="paragraph"></p>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $("#paragraph").text($.Game.gName);
});
```

Comment: Currently im trying this, but I can't get it to show any text:
`<script>
 $(document).load(function() 
  {
      $("#paragraph").text("dqwdqwdqwd");
  }); 
  </script>
  
  <div data-role="content"> 
   <p id="paragraph"></p>
  </div>`

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is being loaded successfully? And are there any Javascript errors in the console?

Comment: I can't find any errors in the log and I seem to be able to read variables from the namespace and show them through alert().

Comment: Try this: `$(document).load(function() { alert("jQuery loading successfully."); });` Tell me if you see the alert.

Comment: I tried it in both the head and body tags, but nothing appeared. I guess I have some problem with my setup.

Comment: Then your jQuery isn't being loaded properly. It must appear before your other script and should look like this: `<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>` where you would replace `jquery-1.7.2.min.js` with the path and name of your downloaded jQuery file.

Comment: I found that it seems to work as intended if I just put `$("#paragraph").text($.Game.gName);` in the beginning of the page declaration. I have not been able to get the document load function yet though. Thanks for all the help Jeff and Michael:)